# Get name(s) from JSON format column, that not in 2 other columns with names

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I need to create column with name(s) (**Supervisors - can be multiple supervisors at the same time, but also there might not be supervisor at all**) from JSON format column, that not in 2 other column with names (**Employee** and **Client**).

| Id | Employee | Client | AllParticipants |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Justin Bieber | Ariana Grande | [{"ParticipantName":"Justin Bieber"},{"ParticipantName":"Ariana Grande"}] |
| 2 | Lionel Messi | Christiano Ronaldo | [{"ParticipantName":"Christiano Ronaldo"},{"ParticipantName":"Lionel Messi"}] |
| 3 | Nicolas Cage | Robert De Niro | [{"ParticipantName":"Robert De Niro"},{"ParticipantName":"Nicolas Cage"},{"ParticipantName":"Brad Pitt"}] |
| 4 | Harry Potter | Ron Weasley | [{"ParticipantName":"Ron Weasley"},{"ParticipantName":"Albus Dumbldor"},{"ParticipantName":"Harry Potter"},{"ParticipantName":"Lord Voldemort"}] |
| 5 | Tom Holland | Henry Cavill | [{"ParticipantName":"Henry Cavill"},{"ParticipantName":"Tom Holland"}] |
| 6 | Spider Man | Venom | [{"ParticipantName":"Venom"},{"ParticipantName":"Iron Man"},{"ParticipantName":"Superman"},{"ParticipantName":"Spider Man"}] |
| 7 | Andrew Garfield | Leonardo DiCaprio | [{"ParticipantName":"Tom Cruise"},{"ParticipantName":"Andrew Garfield"},{"ParticipantName":"Leonardo DiCaprio"}] |
| 8 | Dwayne Johnson | Jennifer Lawrence | [{"ParticipantName":"Jennifer Lawrence"},{"ParticipantName":"Dwayne Johnson"}] |

The output column I need:

```
      Supervisors

NULL
NULL
Brad Pitt
Albus Dumbldor, Lord Voldemort
NULL
Iron Man, Superman
Tom Cruise
NULL
```

I've tried to create extra columns to use Case expression after that, but it seems too complex.

```
SELECT *, 
    JSON_VALUE(w.AllParticipants,'$[0].ParticipantName') AS ParticipantName1,
    JSON_VALUE(w.AllParticipants,'$[1].ParticipantName') AS ParticipantName2,
    JSON_VALUE(w.AllParticipants,'$[2].ParticipantName') AS ParticipantName3,
    JSON_VALUE(w.AllParticipants,'$[3].ParticipantName') AS ParticipantName4
FROM Work AS w
```

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to compare values and extract only unique ones.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Iptr, your code works.
Dale K, I edited the post.
Thank You.

Comment: @Iptr, if there are 2 Supervisors for the record, how can I duplicate row, so there is only 1 Supervisor per row. (I need to perform aggregation after that, grouped by unique supervisor.